# SQL Server table ID approachs to max length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, long-integer, sqldatatypes

I have code first MVC 4 application with SQL Server 2008.

One of my tables is used much, so, many data stored on it in every day and after some time I delete old data. That is why, element's `ID` increases speedily.

I defined it's `ID` as `int` type in the model. I am worry about table will fill after some time.

What will I do if table ID will arrive max length? I never meet with this situation.

My second question is that, if I will change ID's type from `int` to `long` type, then export-import database, will this `long` type affect (reduce) speed of the site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row **every second**, every day of the year, all year long -- then you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ...

If you're afraid - what does this command tell you?

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('your-table-name-here')
```

Are you ***really*** getting close to 2,147,483,647 - or are you still a ways away??

If you should be getting "too close": you can always change the column's datatype to be `BIGINT` - if you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Comment: Thanks for advance info. I saw "int" is enough big number. In my project  approximately I add 1 row in second. So, "int" type still is enough for me.. It will fill when I die ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't any effective method to prevent reaching the limit of the auto-increased identity. You can set it to a data type big enough to last long when you create the table. But, here's one solution I can think of.

Create a new temp table with the same data structure, with the auto-increament column already included and set as primary key. Then, inside the Management Studio, import the data into the new table from the old table. When you are asked to copy the data or write your own query, just choose to write the query, and select everything from your old table except the ID. This can reset the identity to start back from 1. You can delete the old table after that and rename the new temp table. Although you have to right click the database itself to access the Import and Export command, you can set the source and destination database as the same in the options.

This method is pretty much easy and I've done it myself a couple of times.

Comment: Also, you can keep your old table and play with the new one as far as you are satisfied with the result. So, it's pretty harmless to your data.